# Proper permission management when using CQRS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I use Command Query Separation in my system.

To describe the problem lets start with an example. Let's say we have a code as follows:

```
public class TenancyController : ControllerBase{
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateTenancy(CreateTenancyRto rto){

      // 1. Run Blah1Command
      // 2. Run Blah2Command
      // 3. Run Bar1Query
      // 4. Run Blah3Command
      // 5. Run Bar2Query
      // ...
      // n. Run BlahNCommand
      // n+1. Run BarNQuery

      //example how to run a command in the system:
      var command = new UploadTemplatePackageCommand
      {
          Comment = package.Comment,
          Data = Request.Body,
          TemplatePackageId = id
      };
      await _commandDispatcher.DispatchAsync(command);

      return Ok();
    }
}
```

The `CreateTenancy` has a very complex implementation and runs many different queries and commands.

- Each command or query can be reused in other places of the system.
- Each Command has a CommandHandler
- Each Query has a QueryHandler

Example:

```
public class UploadTemplatePackageCommandHandler : PermissionedCommandHandler<UploadTemplatePackageCommand>
    {
        //ctor

        protected override Task<IEnumerable<PermissionDemand>> GetPermissionDemandsAsync(UploadTemplatePackageCommand command) {
          //return list of demands
        }

        protected override async Task HandleCommandAsync(UploadTemplatePackageCommand command)
        {
          //some business logic
        }           
}
```

Every time you try to run the command or query there is a permission check. The problem which appears in the `CreateTenancy` is when you run let's say 10 commands.
There can be a case when you have permissions to all of the first 9 commands but you are missing some permissions to run the last command. In such a situation you can make some complex modifications to the system running these 9 commands and at the end, you are not able to finish the whole transaction because you are not able to run the last command. In such a case, there is a need to make a complex rollback.

I believe that in the above example the permission check should be done only once at the very beginning of the whole transaction but I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve this.

My **first** idea is to create a command called let's say `CreateTenancyCommand` and in the `HandleCommandAsync` place the whole logic from `CreateTenancy(CreateTenancyRto rto)`
So it would look like:

```
public class CreateTenancyCommand : PermissionedCommandHandler<UploadTemplatePackageCommand>
{
        //ctor

        protected override Task<IEnumerable<PermissionDemand>> GetPermissionDemandsAsync(UploadTemplatePackageCommand command) {
          //return list of demands
        }

        protected override async Task HandleCommandAsync(UploadTemplatePackageCommand command)
        {
          // 1. Run Blah1Command
          // 2. Run Blah2Command
          // 3. Run Bar1Query
          // 4. Run Blah3Command
          // 5. Run Bar2Query
          // ...
          // n. Run BlahNCommand
          // n+1. Run BarNQuery
        }           
    }
```

I'm not sure if it's a good approach to invoke a command inside a command handler of another command? 
I think that each command handler should be independent.

Am I right that the permission check should happen only once?
If yes- how to do the permission check in the case when you want to run a command to modify the database and then return some data to the client?
In such a case, you would need to do 2 permission checks...
There can be a theoretical case when you modify the database running the command and then cannot run a query which only reads the database because you are missing some of the permissions. It can be very problematic for the developer to detect such a situation if the system is big and there are hundreds of
different permissions and even the good unit tests coverage can fail.

My **second** idea is to create some kind of wrapper or extra layer above the commands and queries and do the permission check there
but not sure how to implement it.

What is the proper way to do the permissions check in the described transaction `CreateTenancy` which is implemented in the action of the controller in the above example?

Answer (score 1):

In a situation where you have some sort of process which requires multiple commands / service calls to carry out the process, then this is an ideal candidate for a DomainService.

A DomainService is by definition one which has some Domain Knowledge, and is used to facilitate a process which interacts with multiple Aggregates / services.

In this instance I would look to have your Controller Action call a CQRS Command/CommandHandler.  That CommandHandler will take the domain service as a single dependency.  The CommandHandler then has the single responsibility of calling the Domain Service method.

This then means your CreateTenancy process is contained in one place, The DomainService.

I typically have my CommandHandlers simply call into service methods.  Therefore a DomainService can call into multiple services to perform it's function, rather than calling into multiple CommandHandlers.  I treat the Command Handlers as a facade through which my Controllers can access the Domain.

When it comes to permissions, I typically first decide whether the users authorisation to carry out a process is a Domain issue.  If so, I will typically create an Interface to describe the users permissions.  And also, I will typically create an Interface for this specific to the Bounded Context I am working in.  So in this case you may have something like:

```
public interface ITenancyUserPermissions
{
     bool CanCreateTenancy(string userId);
}
```

I would then have the ITenancyUserPermission interface be a dependancy in my CommandValidator:

```
    public class CommandValidator : AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        private ITenancyUserPermissions _permissions;

        public CommandValidator(ITenancyUserPermissions permissions)
        {
           _permissions = permissions;

            RuleFor(r => r).Must(HavePermissionToCreateTenancy).WithMessage("You do not have permission to create a tenancy.");
        }

        public bool HavePermissionToCreateTenancy(Command command)
        {
             return _permissions.CanCreateTenancy(command.UserId);
        }

    }
```

You said that the permission to create a Tenancy is dependent on the permission to perform the other tasks / commands.  Those other commands would have their own set of Permission Interfaces.  And then ultimately within your application you would have an implementation of these interfaces such as:

```
public class UserPermissions : ITenancyUserPermissions, IBlah1Permissions, IBlah2Permissions
{

    public bool CanCreateTenancy(string userId)
    {
        return CanBlah1 && CanBlah2;
    }

    public bool CanBlah1(string userID)
    {
        return _authService.Can("Blah1", userID);            
    }

    public bool CanBlah2(string userID)
    {
        return _authService.Can("Blah2", userID);
    }
}
```

In my case I use a ABAC system, with the policy stored and processed as a XACML file.

Using the above method may mean you have slightly more code, and several Permissions interfaces, but it does mean that any permissions you define are specific to the Bounded Context you are working within.  I feel this is better than having a Domain Model wide IUserPermissions interface, which may define methods which of no relevance, and/or confusing in your Tenancy bounded context.

This means you can check user permissions in your QueryValidator or CommandValidator instances.  And of course you can use the implementation of your IPermission interfaces at the UI level to control which buttons / functions etc are shown to the user.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "The Proper Way",  but I'd suggest that you could approach the solution from the following angle.

Usage of the word `Controller` in your names and returning `Ok()` lets me understand that you are handling an http request. But what is happening inside is a part of a business use case that has nothing to deal with http. So, you'd better get some Onion-ish and introduce a (business) application layer.

This way, your http controller would be responsible for: 1) Parsing create tenancy http request into a create tenancy business request - i.e. the request object model in terms of domain language void of any infrastructure terms. 2) Formatting business response into an http response including translating business errors into http errors.

So, what you get entering the application layer is a business create tenancy request. But it's not a command yet. I can't remember the source, but someone once said, that command should be internal to a domain. It cannot come from outside. You may consider a command to be a comprehensive object model necessary to make a decision whether to change an application's state. So, my suggestion is that in your business application layer you build a command not only from business request, but also from results of all these queries, including queries to necessary permission read models.

Next, you may have a separate decision-making business core of a system that takes a command (a value object) with all the comprehensive data, applies a pure decision-making function and returns a decision, also a value object (event or rejection), containing, again, all necessary data calculated from the command.

Then, when your business application layer gets back a decision, it can execute it, writing to event stores or repositories, logging, firing events and ultimately producing a business response to the controller.

In most cases you'll be ok with this single-step decision-making process. If it needs more than a single step - maybe it's a hint to reconsider the business flow, because it gets too complex for a single http request processing.

This way you'll get all the permissions before handling a command. So, your business core will be able to make a decision whether those permissions are sufficient to proceed. It also may make a decision-making logic much more testable and, therefore, reliable. Because it is the main part that should be tested in any calculation flow branch.

Keep in mind that this approach leans toward eventual consistency, which you have anyway in a distributed system. Though, if interacting with a single database, you may run an application-layer code in a single transaction. I suppose, though, that you deal with eventual consistency anyway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "I can't remember the source, but someone once said, that command should be internal to a domain. It cannot come from outside." This is very interesting comment. If you remember the source I'd be gratitude if you can write it down here :)